# WPF Canvas Is rectangle at position

Tags: c#, wpf, object, wpf-controls, position

How can I check if a rectangle object is at a specific position in a canvas? The only solution I found is going through all children in the canvas and check if their position matches, but I don't think that is a good solution.

So I need something like `Canvas.IsRectangleAtPosition(Point x)`, is there anything like that?

If not, how can I implement such a method?

Kind regards

Comment: Do you mean to find the first child (or all children) that covers a certain position?

Comment: Thats right :) and there is only one rectangle at a position, not two overlapping, so I just have to check if at a certain position there is a rectangle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to find the top-most UI element (the one that would get mouse input) you could simply call [InputHitTest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.inputhittest.aspx).

```
Point pos = ...
Rectangle rect = canvas.InputHitTest(pos) as Rectangle;
```

You could also use [VisualTreeHelper.HitTest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms608752.aspx).

```
Rectangle rect = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(canvas, pos).VisualHit as Rectangle;
```

Comment: It does not seem to help, if I start the program and it comes to that point it says something with NullReferenceException :/ is there a solution or can I check the colour (the one which the user sees) of a point in the canvas?

Comment: You should find out where the NullReferenceException comes from. Try debugging.